# Creating a new columns for every value in a row

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have the follow pandas data frame:

```
name        state   postcode
coles       vic      2501
woolworth   nsw      3409
big w       act      3201
target      vic      1089
```

I need to convert this set to look like this , I normally do manually however this time I have many values in the state and I'm aiming to have them in a column with yes and no.In Stata I would loop through, however in Python Im a bit lost.

```
name       state    postcode    VIC  NSW    ACT  NT
coles       VIC      2501        Y    N      N   N
woolworth   NSW      3409        N    Y      N   N
big w       ACT      3201        N    N      Y   N
target      NT       1089        N    N      N   Y
```

Comment: As of Pandas 0.16.0+, you can also use `assign`, which assigns new columns to a DataFrame and returns a new object (a copy) with all the original columns in addition to the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for `N` and `Y`:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['state']).replace({0:'N', 1:'Y'}))
print (df)
        name state  postcode act nsw vic
0      coles   vic      2501   N   N   Y
1  woolworth   nsw      3409   N   Y   N
2      big w   act      3201   Y   N   N
3     target   vic      1089   N   N   T
```

Or convert to `bool`:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['state']).astype(bool))
print (df)
        name state  postcode    act    nsw    vic
0      coles   vic      2501  False  False   True
1  woolworth   nsw      3409  False   True  False
2      big w   act      3201   True  False  False
3     target   vic      1089  False  False   True
```

Or if possible `0` and `1` values:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df['state']))
print (df)
        name state  postcode  act  nsw  vic
0      coles   vic      2501    0    0    1
1  woolworth   nsw      3409    0    1    0
2      big w   act      3201    1    0    0
3     target   vic      1089    0    0    1
```

Comment: A big plus !!! @jezrael , you just made my day forever as I can apply this now in some economic models. Fantastic!!